# Symfony Propel criteria

Tags: mysql, symfony1, criteria, propel

Is there any possible way to convert the MySQL object into criteria object? I tried this query:

```
select 
  p.disrepid, 
  p.subject, p.body, 
  c.disrepid as disrepid1, 
  c.subject as subject1, 
  c.body as body1 
from discusreply as p, discusreply as c 
where p.distopid=' . $this->id . ' 
  and (c.disrepid = p.parentid or c.parentid = p.distopid) 
order by p.disrepid ASC
```

I tried a lot for converting this query into a `Criteria`, But nothing happened. I want this criteria object for passing this into Pager class for completing the pagination.
`$pager->setCriteria($c);`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use your own SQL do perform a query, but there is no automated way to turn sql into a Criteria object.

```
$con = Propel::getConnection(DATABASE_NAME);
$sql = "SELECT books.* FROM books 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM review WHERE book_id = book.id)";
$stmt = $con->createStatement();
$rs = $stmt->executeQuery($sql, ResultSet::FETCHMODE_NUM);
$books = BookPeer::populateObjects($rs);
```

This bypasses Criterion objects all together. You mentioned wanting a criteria object so you could feed this into a pager. You can instead set a custom select method into your pager, which will then perform your custom query. If you need to pass a parameter into this, I would recommend extending sfPropel with your own pager class that can optionally pass parameters to your peer select methods so you don't have to use Criteria objects at all. As a quick alternative, you can do something like this, using your Criteria as a container for your select parameters:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(DiscussreplyPeer::ID, $myId);
$pager = new sfPropelPager();
$pager->setCriteria($c);
$pager->setPeerMethod('getReplies');
```

And then in your peer class:

```
public static function getReplies(Criteria $c) {
    $map = $c->getMap();
    $replyId = $map[DiscussreplyPeer::ID]->getValue();

    $con = Propel::getConnection(DATABASE_NAME);
    $sql = "select p.disrepid, p.subject, p.body, c.disrepid as disrepid1, c.subject as subject1, c.body as body1 from discusreply as p, discusreply as c where p.distopid=? and (c.disrepid = p.parentid or c.parentid = p.distopid) order by p.disrepid ASC";

    $stmt = $con->prepareStatement($sql);
    $stmt->setString(1, $replyId);

    $rs = $stmt->executeQuery();

    $results = array();
    while ($rs->next()) {
      // for example
        $results['disrepid'] = $rs->getInt('disrepid');
    }

    return $results;
}
```

More tips on propel and symfony can be found at:
http://stereointeractive.com/blog/2007/06/12/propel-queries-using-custom-sql-peer-classes-and-criterion-objects/

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://propel.jondh.me.uk/) will help a lot for learning to write criteria - you can use it to generate criteria code from pseudo SQL. I would also recommend grabbing the [Symfony/Propel cheat sheets](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/CheatSheets).

For your query in particular you will want something like this:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(discusreply::DISREPID, discusreply::PARENTID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);  
$c->clearSelectColumns();
$c->addSelectColumn(discusreplyPeer::Disrepid); 
...
$c->add(discusreplyPeer::DISTOPID, $this->id, Criteria::EQUAL);
... 
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(discusreply::DISREPID);
```

I'm not sure that the Criteria system supports multiple clauses for an inner join so you may have to revert back to ad-hoc SQL for this query (if it does I would love to know how). The following code will create a ResultSet object similar to what you would get from simple database abstraction layers.

```
$sql = "SELECT ...";
$dbh = Propel::getConnection([DB]);
$sth = $dbh->createStatement();
$res = $sth->executeQuery($sql, ResultSet::FETCHMODE_NUM);
```

I don't think there is much of a disadvantage to using the ad-hoc method on a query like this since you will have to deal with ResultSet objects rather than table-specific objects when you are returning only specific columns.

Comment: I discovered you can do something like $c->addJoin(TABLE_A::ID, TABLE_B::ID.' AND '.TABLE_B::VALUE.' > 0', Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
(with propel 1.2, not 1.3) to add multiple conditions to joins.

Answer (score 2):

You can try auto-generating the criteria from sql using [this site](http://propel.jondh.me.uk/).